# How can I set a message if db_delete deleted one or more rows

Tags: 7, database

In drupal 6 my code worked like this:

```
if (db_query("DELETE FROM {,ymodule_fields} WHERE conid = %d", $conid)) {
  drupal_set_message(t("Deleted fields."));
}
```

Now I'm supposed to use db_delete.

Will this code work?  I know db_delete returns a DeleteQuery object so I'm assuming it's going to evaluate to true every time.  I can't test my module yet because I'm doing a lot of work updating the code that creates cck fields to use core fields.  Is DeleteQuery a PDO that has the `rowCount` method?

```
if (db_delete('mymodule_fields')
  ->condition('conid', $conid)
  ->execute()) {
  drupal_set_message(t("Deleted Fields."));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, `db_delete()` returns an object so you can continue working with the object, but the last method called (the method whose return value your conditional is really checking) in your statement is `Query::execute`, which returns boolean `TRUE` or `FALSE` indicating whether the query worked. So, ultimately the whole statement:

```
db_delete('drealty_fields')
  ->condition('conid', $conid)
  ->execute();
```

Should return `TRUE` or `FALSE` since you're ultimately executing the `Query::execute` method. The workflow is just that you call `db_delete()`, which returns an object, `Query::condition`, returns an object, then `Query::execute` returns boolean, but your conditional is just getting and checking the return value of the last method called - `execute` - rather than the return value of `db_delete()`. Essentially, the `db_delete()` return value was already operated on by continuing with a condition, and the condition's return value is inconsequential because it was operated on by `execute`, thus the execute's return value is the only one really getting sent back to the `if` statement. Make sense?

So, in essence each of these examples should give the same results:

```
$query = db_delete('drealty_fields');
$query->condition('conid', $conid);
$success = $query->execute();
if ($success) {
  // Do something.
}

$query = db_delete('drealty_fields');
$query->condition('conid', $conid);
if ($query->execute()) {
  // Do something.
}

if (db_delete('drealty_field's)->condition('conid', $conid)->execute()) {
  // Do something.
}
```